# Having trouble with hard page refresh in Firefox/MacOS

Tags: macos, firefox

I made some alterations to a page, and, using Firefox, did a Shift-Command-R to hard reload it. When I do that, Firefox reloads the new page as expected, but if I then do an ordinary page reload (e.g. Command-R) reloads the old version of the page.

I don't get this behavior using Chrome; I only have to do the hard page reload once, and the new version loads from then on with an ordinary page reload. So it doesn't look like this has anything to do with my hosting service (BlueHost).

I've tried:

1. Clearing the cache, using Firefox/Preferences/Advanced/Network and hitting the "Clear Now" button in the "Cached Web Content" area.
2. Deleting all cookies associated with the site containing the page.
3. Quitting Firefox and opening it again.

After doing all of these, I still get the same behavior: Shift-Command-R loads the new version of the page, and Command-R loads the old one.

Firefox version is 52.9.0; MacOS version is 10.13.6.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is by design in **FireFox**:

> Reload <kbd>F5</kbd> (or) <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

```
// does not override cache
```

> Reload (override cache)   <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> +
>   <kbd>R</kbd>

```
// override cache
```

↳ [Keyboard shortcuts - Perform common Firefox tasks quickly](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_navigation)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I got the feeling that what you have described is by design. But how do you get an old page out of the cache, when you have updated your website? I would have thought that "clearing the cache" was the way to do that.

Comment: I suppose it might depend on how you are clearing it or possible that FireFox is not clearing everything completely out and reloading the same old thing. I've noticed similar behavior before after clearing everything and it was only after I did shift-command-r or closed the browser and restarted the new page loaded. I'm not sure the reason for this, but maybe they could tell you more on the Mozilla support forums perhaps.

Comment: At this point, I've cleared the cache again and reloaded Firefox, and the new page is showing. Go figure. Thanks for your input!